# Switch to frame/object with IeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage, that consist of **frame** implemented as **object** tag:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="methods.isDefined()">
<!--[if IE]> <object classid="clsid:25312120-03F9-11CF-8222-00AA44486F13" ng-attr-data="{{objectUrl}}"></object> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object ng-attr-data="{{objectUrl}}" type="text/html" data="/some-app/"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```

At least I guess this is a frame. I can get it's content using **(Python)**:

for **Firefox**:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

for **Chrome**:

```
frame = find_element_by_css_selector("object")
driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
```

but I don't know how to access it witch **IE driver**. I tried both ways mentioned above, I have also tried switch to object element, string "object", classid and so on, but I still get `NoSuchFrameException: No frame found`.
Any ideas?